# Как рисовать в виджете

Tags: c++, qt5

помогите разобраться в чем засада.
QT5
делаю форму окна, в ней делаю c с помощью Desing делаю объект Qwidget w;
Хочу чтобы QPainter отрисовал в моем виджете ui->w - не хочет рисовать.

заголовок widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

файл формы
widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget ::  paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter *p = new QPainter();
    p->begin(ui->w);
    p->drawLine(10,10,30,30);
}
```

Вроде бы все просто , но не хочет рисовать

```
QPainter *p = new QPainter(ui->w);
```

Пишет

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

Вариант

```
QPainter *p = new QPainter(this);
```

рисует в родительском окне.

где я ошибся?

Comment: Сделайте свой виджет от QWidget, в нем переопределите paintEvent. Добавьте через код этот виджет на нужный виджет в форме (`ui->w->setLayout(layout);` + `layout->addWidget(<объект вашего виджета с paintEvent>)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш виджет для рисования:

```cpp
class MyPaintedWidget : public QWidget {
    ...
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Есть несколько вариантов как его добавить на родителя, самый прямой - программно:

```cpp
// Если layout не был добавлен в Дизайнере, то добавляем
// иначе эту строчку выполнять не нужно
ui->parentWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout()); // Например QVBoxLayout, конечно можно и другой

ui->parentWidget->layout(new MyPaintedWidget());
```

Или так:

```
MyPaintedWidget* paintedWidget = new MyPaintedWidget(ui->parentWidget);
```

В этом случае неважно есть layout у родителя, или нет

Comment: СПАСИБО! заработало.